# python variable name resolve mechanism?

Tags: python, variables

How python resolves variable name?In the example at below .
Why not print(Base) inside ChildA not refer to Base class?
Is the Base in ChildA(Base) is referred to Bass class or string class or 'String'?

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print( "Base created")

class ChildA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print(Base)
        Base.__init__(self)


Base = 'string'
ChildA()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lookup occurs dynamically at the time the code is executed.  When Python gets to the line `print(Base)`, it looks for a local variable named Base, and then looks up and up in enclosing scopes for a name `Base`.  In this case, it finds one in the global namespace, and, at the time you call `ChildA()`, that variable is a string.

In other words, free (that is, non-local) variables in a function really are free: what they refer to is not "locked" at the time the function is defined, but is looked up anew each time the function is called.

Note that the Base in `class ChildA(Base)` does unambiguously refer to the `Base` class in your example.  That's because the class definition is only executed once, and at that time, the name `Base` is pointing to that class.

Answer (score 4):

In the following sentence,

```
Base = 'string'
```

the code overwrite `Base` with a string object.

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print( "Base created")
...
>>> class ChildA(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print(Base)
...         Base.__init__(self)
...
>>> Base
<class '__main__.Base'>
>>> Base = 'string' # <-------
>>> Base
'string'
```